# Hidden internal links in homepage (that can be revealed by onclick event) for SEO?

Tags: javascript, html, seo

I was thinking I would have around 4 pictures with `onclick` events where they would each open up and reveal 10 links each (so around 40 links on homepage on `display:none`). I was wondering if that would have a negative impact on SEO?

*Would Google be able to crawl into these?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO questions are better suited for [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If they are internal links, don't worry. Google does not take them into account. No negative impact on SEO.

Google will be able to crawl these if they are revealed via Javascript. If you worry Google bots won't find them, put them in a sitemap.